# Custom contact in own database

Tags: android, android-contacts

**Situation:**
In our application we have data objects referred to as clients.
We also have other data objects which link to these clients by using the primary unique key `client._id`.

The application obtains this information from an external webserver and stores them in a SQLite database. Now its my task to see if its interesting for us to sync our clients with the android contacts.

**Option 1:**
From what I have seen you can add new contacts to the system using `ContentProviderOperation`. I noticed that I can add custom data to the `RawContact`. This means I can store all the client related information into the system instead of my own database.

**Option 2:**
Another option would be to keep my SQLite database with the clients and maintain a `RawContact` based on this information. This means that they need to notify eachother on insert, change and delete.

Given these 2 options, which one would be the better pick for me and why? (Or is there a better option available which I'm not aware of?)

Answer (score 0):

I would question whether it is worth linking the two at all. In my experience it is not. It might look attractive at first glance, but the more you delve into it the more you will realise that it is a non-starter.

Comment: So your saying not to touch contacts at all and continue using my own client list for user interaction?